# fetching values from props "ReactJs& JavaScript"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have issues with fetching the following values from props, here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

> const files = updatedValue.files;
>
> const firstName = updatedValue.firstName;
>
> const lastname = updatedValue.lastname;

```
onChange = updatedValue => {


const files = updatedValue.files;
const firstName = updatedValue.firstName;
const lastname = updatedValue.lastname;

//I need to use the values here 


};

render() {
return (
<div className="App">
<Form onChange={fields => this.onChange(fields)} />
<p>

</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can have the callback function on this.setState

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      files: []
    }
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({firstName: "Sample", lastName:"Test"}, () => {
      console.log(`${this.state.firstName} ${this.state.lastName}`)
      // output will be Sample Test
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Sample Button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SetState is an async, you can have a look through on this one [set State async !!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)